# Why program (global) scope variables must be __constant?

Tags: global-variables, opencl

I am new to OpenCL and really confused by this restriction. For example, if I want to write a LCG, I have to make the state word be modifiable to both `rand()` and `srand()`. In ANSI C, I will do that with something like:

```
/* ANSI C */
static unsigned long _holdrand = 1; /* Global! */

unsigned long rand(){
    _holdrand = _holdrand * 214013L + 2531011L;
    return (_holdrand >> 16) & 0x7FFF; 
}
void srand( unsigned long seed ){
    _holdrand = seed;
}
```

But OpenCL restrict all global scope variables being `__constant`. I could move `_holdrand` into function scope, and return it's pointer out of that function.

```
/* OpenCL C */
uint* holdrand(){
    __private static uint _holdrand = 1;
    return &_holdrand;
}

uint rand(){
    *holdrand() = *holdrand() * 214013L + 2531011L;
    return (*holdrand() >> 16) & 0x7FFF; 
}
void srand( uint seed ){
    *holdrand() = seed;
}
```

It works fine and I don't know if this is a good solution. The restriction made nonsense, I just avoided it by adding more weird code.

```
__private uint _holdrand = 1;
/* It should be the same thing... Why this is not allowed? */
```

Since the return-a-pointer-of-static manner will behave exactly the same as the global scope variable approach in ANSI C, I couldn't understand what the restriction meaning for. Could someone explain why? Did I missed something? What should I do to make `_holdrand` modifiable in two different functions in this example?

Comment: Interesting.  Good point.  Good idea :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Briefly - OpenCL program lifetime & memory layout is different from C program. In OpenCL, you don't have stack, heap, etc. Constant memory is (usually) very fast & little amount of on-chip memory, IO operations to which has the same order of performance in comparison to register operations. So, it may have limitations for write operations from Work Items.

In every NDRange (usually) there are thousands of Work Items (WI). Imagine what performance you can achieve if, say, 512 threads are reading/writing same variable. That's why you have 4 address spaces:

- `__private` for every WI
- `__local` for all WIs inside Work Group
- `__global` for all WI within NDRange
- `__constant` for global read-only variables

If your `rand()` & `srand()` functions are WI-specific, you should use private memory. An alternative way is to have variables you need in global address space. But in this case be very careful with race conditions.

OpenCL can be run on the vast variety of devices, that's why some restrictions look too strong.

Comment: Yes, I want each WI preserve a different state. It should be in the __private address space. But if the state word cannot be placed in program scope, where should I declare it? I cannot declare `__private` variables outside a function either.

Comment: Simplest way is to create array of values in global memory. Every WI reads and writes, using it's ID as index in array.

Comment: Declare it inside the kernel. Then call srand() and rand() with an aditional parameter which will be the value of "_holdrand" for that work item storage. Simple.

Comment: So I must pass the `_holdrand` through all of the callers. Sounds terrible. Why so complicated in OpenCL? Is this for the portability to FPGAs?

Comment: If you make your C multi-threaded, you will probably end up with same result

Comment: In multi-threading C I can just add the `__thread` or `__declspec(thread)` specifier to use auto TLS mechanism, it should work like `__private` here.