# Metal - Namespace variable that is local to a thread?

Tags: c++, random, gpu, gpgpu, metal

I'm trying to create a Pseudo Random Number Generator (PRNG) in Metal, akin to `thrust`'s RNG , where every time you call the RNG *within a thread* it produces a different random number given a particular seed, which in this case, will be the `thread_position_in_grid`. I have it set up perfectly, and I get a nice uniformly random picture right now using the code I have.

However, my code only works once per thread. I want to implement a `next_rng()` function that returns a new `rng` using the last result as a seed. I am having trouble storing that last result, however, as my RNG is a namespace, and I can only store the last result in `constant` address space, which is un-updateable. Is there any way to get around this/restructure my code to avoid this?

The best help I could find online was [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471466/why-program-global-scope-variables-must-be-constant) that unfortunately doesn't work with me because I can't declare a variable as static within a function as they do in their solution.

**I'm open for restructuring my code in any way if that helps. Can I maybe turn this into a static class or a class or something? No clue, but I just want a PRNG**

My code (simplified) basically has the same structure as that post's:

```
namespace metal_rng {

    thread unsigned* last_seed() {
        thread uint last_seed = 1; // Doesn't work because last-seed falls out of scope after the function quits

        // The following comment line doesn't even compile:
        // thread static uint last_seed = 1;

        return &last_seed;
    }

    unsigned TausStep(const unsigned z, const int s1, const int s2, const int s3, const unsigned M)
    {
        unsigned b=(((z << s1) ^ z) >> s2);
        return (((z & M) << s3) ^ b);
    }

    device float rng(const int initial_seed) {
        int seed = initial_seed * 1099087573UL;

        unsigned hashed = (1664525*(*last_seed()) + 1013904223UL);
        *last_seed() = hashed
        return (hashed) * 2.3283064365387e-10;
    }

    device float next_rng() {
          if (*last_seed() == 0) {
              return 0.0;
          } else {
              unsigned hashed = (1664525*(*last_seed()) + 1013904223UL);
              return (hashed) * 2.3283064365387e-10;
          }
    }
}
```

#### Edit:

Framework is done and packaged neatly here: [Link](https://github.com/YoussefV/Loki/tree/master)

Comment: What does the client code of this RNG code look like? You should probably create a class to represent the RNG with the functions as member functions and the state (last seed) as a member variable. You would create an instance of this class as a local in the calling code, initialized with the initial seed. If you need to use it in multiple functions, you'll have to pass a reference to the instance around, which is annoying but doable.

Comment: I'm using it for a monte carlo path tracer. Your suggestions worked! I'm in the process of packaging up the code into a neat framework for anyone to use. I'll share a link to the repo as soon as I'm done! Thanks a bunch (:

Comment: [Link to the repo as mentioned before](https://github.com/YoussefV/Loki). There are also instructions on how to use the RNG in the repo for any future wanderers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using @KenThomases' suggestions and I just created a class for the RNG. I packaged the code and called the RNG `Loki`. [Here is the link to the repo](https://github.com/YoussefV/Loki) if anyone wants to use it in the future.