# How to get a random number in Metal shader?

Tags: random, metal

How would I go about getting a random number in a Metal shader?

I searched for "random" in The Metal Shading Language Specification, but found nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I was working on a Random Number Generator for another project and was wanting to package it into a neat framework for a while.

Your question pushed me to do just that. If you don't mind the shameless plug, [here](https://github.com/YoussefV/Loki/tree/master) is a very simple framework that will generate a random number for you in a metal shader based on (up to) three seeds that you give it. The code is based on the [following research paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/368/1/012024/meta) that describes how to create random numbers on parallel processors for Monte Carlo simulations. It also has a (theoretical) period of `2^121` so it should be good for most reasonable calculations that can be done on a GPU.

All you have to call in your shader is an intializer, then you call `rand()`, like so:

```
// Initialize a random number generator, seeds 2 and 3 are optional
Loki rng = Loki(seed1, seed2, seed3);

// get a random float [0,1)
float random_float = rng.rand();
```

I also included a sample project in the repo so you can see how it is used.

Comment: The implementation looks great, but I do not see a license in the GitHub repo. Is that something you can provide?

Comment: I can add a license if you need it, but I'll tell you here you can use Loki for any purposes you want: commercial, personal, educational, etc... Attribution would be nice, but idrc. This was a side project that I haven't touched since

Comment: Thank you for providing that. I think adding a license file to the repo would be best, just to make it easier for people who do not find this SO post. This is a link to an MIT License if you don't have it handy. https://opensource.org/license/mit/

Answer (score 6):

It looks like there's not one built in. This example code for [MetalShaderShowcase/AAPLWoodShader.metal](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MetalShaderShowcase/Listings/MetalShaderShowcase_AAPLWoodShader_metal.html) defines its own simple `rand` function.

```
// Generate a random float in the range [0.0f, 1.0f] using x, y, and z (based on the xor128 algorithm)
float rand(int x, int y, int z)
{
    int seed = x + y * 57 + z * 241;
    seed= (seed<< 13) ^ seed;
    return (( 1.0 - ( (seed * (seed * seed * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 2147483647) / 1073741824.0f) + 1.0f) / 2.0f;
}
```

Comment: Are there any requirement on the x, y, z? I generate the noise with pixel position and system. The noise looks periodic, so it's not good.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at `[pcg-random]`, it's very simple and fast, more importantly it's fast. And it's super easy to modify their C code for Metal. https://www.pcg-random.org/

```
typedef struct { uint64_t state;  uint64_t inc; } pcg32_random_t;

void pcg32_srandom_r(thread pcg32_random_t* rng, uint64_t initstate, uint64_t initseq)
{
    rng->state = 0U;
    rng->inc = (initseq << 1u) | 1u;
    pcg32_random_r(rng);
    rng->state += initstate;
    pcg32_random_r(rng);
}

uint32_t pcg32_random_r(thread pcg32_random_t* rng)
{
    uint64_t oldstate = rng->state;
    rng->state = oldstate * 6364136223846793005ULL + rng->inc;
    uint32_t xorshifted = ((oldstate >> 18u) ^ oldstate) >> 27u;
    uint32_t rot = oldstate >> 59u;
    return (xorshifted >> rot) | (xorshifted << ((-rot) & 31));
}
```

How do I use it?

```
float randomF(thread pcg32_random_t* rng)
{
    //return pcg32_random_r(rng)/float(UINT_MAX);
    return ldexp(float(pcg32_random_r(rng)), -32);
}

pcg32_random_t rng;
pcg32_srandom_r(&rng, pos_grid.x*int_time, pos_grid.y*int_time);

auto randomFloat = randomF(&rng);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of computing the random number on the GPU, you can also compute a bunch of random numbers on the CPU and pass them into a the shader using a uniform / `MTLBuffer`.

Comment: I don't think this solution is a very effective one though for applications that need lots of random numbers generated on the fly though... wouldn't it be better to just create a random number generator in a metal shader?

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees, the randomness has to come from someplace. Even with an RNG implemented in Metal, you'd want/need the seed to come from the CPU to get the initial randomness. If you use something like vertex ID or fragment position as your seed, it won't be random from run to run.

Comment: @KenThomases Well, if we're passing something from the CPU for randomness, it seems like the lightest thing to pass would be a "frame counter" so it actually would be random from run to run. Thanks to [your help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47439008/metal-namespace-variable-that-is-local-to-a-thread) a few weeks ago I actually was able to create [a neat framework](https://github.com/YoussefV/Loki/tree/master) that works very well across multiple iterations. I'd be interested to hear your feedback of all people! (:

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees Huh? If you pass a frame counter, it **won't** be random from run to run. Yes, it will be random from frame to frame within a run, but the next run will start the frame counter over again and you'll just repeat the same sequence as all other runs.

Comment: @KenThomases I thought you meant frame-to-frame, I misread that. The main point of my argument was passing only the seed from CPU to GPU, and doing the generation on the GPU. You can just as simply pass in the time as the seed, that way it **would** be random from run to run.

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees, sure, passing just a random seed value makes sense, depending on how much true randomness you need. But now we're just quibbling about how much random data you send from the CPU. The principle that you need to send some still holds. And it can be a valid choice to send lots and not generate any on the GPU.